# TCHAR array appending w after backslash

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc, char, multibyte

I am coding an C++ MFC app with Multibyte characters, and I am trying to iteratively run through drive letters to check for a USB connection. This part of my code started causing me some problems in debug mode:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
...
    //Possible device path
    TCHAR drivePath[3] = {_T('A'+i), _T(':'), _T('\\')};
...
}
```

The drive never gets found because this array is always appended with a "w" at the end.

For example, for `i=0`, `drivePath=A:\w`

My hypothesis is that it is multibyte/unicode related, but I assumed that by using `TCHAR` and `_T`, that it would take care of that.

Any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never terminated the array with a null character.

```
TCHAR drivePath[3] = {_T('A'+i), _T(':'), _T('\\')};
```

Should be

```
TCHAR drivePath[4] = {_T('A'+i), _T(':'), _T('\\'), _T('\0')};
// or
TCHAR drivePath[] = {_T('A'+i), _T(':'), _T('\\'), _T('\0')};
//             ^^ let the compiler figure out the size
```

Answer (score 3):

And another alternative:

```
TCHAR drivePath[] = { _T("A:\\") };
for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++){
    //Possible device path
    drivePath[0] = ch;
}
```

Comment: That is a little more elegant then what I am doing. Thanks!